# Extract numbers from string literals in a list based on zip function in Python

Tags: python, loops, split, type-conversion

I have a list of strings that represent time in minutes and seconds, e.g.

```
distanceList = [0.56, 0.04, 0.56, 0.44, 0.76] #represents distances traveled
timeList = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s'] # represents time to taken to travel
```

I need to extract these numbers (minutes (m) and seconds (s)) and convert into hours.

So far, I have implemented the zip function and used some list comprehension to extract the numbers individually into lists. However, I am not sure how to get these summed into hours considering they are separated and not always consistent in distances from the colon separator. That's how far I got.

```
for a, b in zip(distanceList, timeList):
nums = [item for subitem in b for item in subitem.split() if item.isdigit()]
print nums
```

Expected results: a list of integers that represent the minutes and seconds.

```
[[5,11],[18,18]...]
```

Received results:

```
['5', '1', '1', '1', '8', '8'....]
```

Comment: Any reason not to use *regexp*?

Comment: I am required to use zip and os methods to extract these numbers.

Comment: Pleas post the complete code. What are timelist and distancelist? Also how do you convert 3 minutes and 5 seconds into hours?

Comment: Apologies; updated.

Comment: in conversion of time into hours, that's another approach I'm wrestling with: there is a decimal representation of min and sec of hours and summed I suppose?

Comment: How are they to be converted into hours? e.g. `5m:11s` should look like what?

Comment: `[[int(item1[:-1]) for item1 in item0.split(":")] for item0 in timeList]` ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "convert into hours"? This step seems to be missing in the expected result.

Comment: Sure: in the above, timeList of course contains times in minutes and seconds. I need to extract those numbers (which I have) and part 2 is to convert 7, 13 (representing minutes and seconds) into  hour time (likely resulting in a decimal representation of hours) ...  30m:00s would equal .50 hours.

I am attempting to calculate the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case "summing into hours" is still relevant: sum `timedelta` objects.

```
from datetime import timedelta

strings =  ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s']

def sum_timestrings(strings):
    min_secs = (s.split(':') for s in strings)
    total = sum((timedelta(minutes=int(m[:-1]), seconds=int(s[:-1]))
                for m, s in min_secs), timedelta())
    return total

total = sum_timestrings(strings)
print(total) # 2:46:37 
print(total.total_seconds()/3600) # 2.7769444444444447
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 5 cents

```py
times = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s']
f = lambda x : int(''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]))
new_times = [[f(s) for u in t.split(":") for s in u.split() ] for t in times]
```

output

```py
[[5, 11], [18, 18], [13, 35], [8, 26], [121, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time_strings = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s']

times = []

for time_string in time_strings:
    tokens = time_string.replace("m", "").replace("s", "").split(":")
    minutes, seconds = map(int, tokens)
    times.append([minutes, seconds])

print(times)
```

Or:

```
time_strings = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s']

times = []

for time_string in time_strings:
    tokens = time_string.split(":")
    minutes, seconds = map(int, [token.strip("ms") for token in tokens])
    times.append([minutes, seconds])

print(times)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 11], [18, 18], [13, 35], [8, 26], [121, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
distance_list = [0.56, 0.04, 0.56, 0.44, 0.76]  # represents distances traveled
time_list = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s']  # represents time to taken to travel
time_list1 = [(t[:t.index('m')], t[t.index(':') + 1: t.index('s')]) for t in time_list]
for d, t in zip(distance_list, time_list1):
    print('{} --> {}'.format(d, t))
```

output

```
0.56 --> ('5', '11')
0.04 --> ('18', '18')
0.56 --> ('13', '35')
0.44 --> ('8', '26')
0.76 --> ('121', '7')
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone..I really appreciate the help. I recognize the poorly written question makes it harder, but I do appreciate you choosing to answer it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
timeList = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s'] # represents time to taken to travel

times = [[int(minute), int(second)]
         for time in timeList
         for lst in [time.split(":")]
         for minute in ["".join([x for x in lst[0] if x.isdigit()])]
         for second in ["".join([y for y in lst[1] if y.isdigit()])]]

print(times)
```

Which yields

```
[[5, 11], [18, 18], [13, 35], [8, 26], [121, 7]]
```

---

Imo a better alternative would be:

```
import re
timeList = ['5m:11s', '18m:18s', '13m:35s', '8m:26s', '121m:7s'] # represents time to taken to travel

rx = re.compile(r'^(\d+)\D+(\d+)')
result = [m.groups() for item in timeList for m in [rx.search(item)]]
print(result)
```